# tex4ebook: html parsing errors when content contains tables

Tags: tables, tex4ht, html, tex4ebook

I'm generating an .epub with tex4ebook. There are two sets of errors that come up during compilation, both related to parsing of html files that contain tables (unbalanced or unexpected tags). Any hints as to how I can resolve these errors would be appreciated.

mwe.tex

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l X}
    A & Apple \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\part{B}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l X}
    B & Banana \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

mwe.mk4

```
local domfilter = require "make4ht-domfilter"
local filter = require "make4ht-filter"
local dom    = require "luaxml-domobject"
local log = logging.new "build file"


local function mwe_parsing(s)
      local status, obj = pcall(function()
          return dom.parse(s)
      end)
      if not status then 
        log:warning("HTML parsing failed")
        log:warning(obj)
        return s 
      end
      obj:traverse_elements(function(el)
      end)
      -- serialize the DOM object back to HTML
      return obj:serialize()
end

local process = filter {mwe_parsing}
Make:match("html$", process)
Make:match("html$", "tidy -m -xml -utf8 -q -i ${filename}")

Make:htlatex {}
```

I've included the output generated during compilation below. If I comment out `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}`, the first set of errors disappears. If I comment out `\part{B}` or `\noindent` the second set of errors disappears.

```
[STATUS]  tex4ebook: Conversion started
[STATUS]  tex4ebook: Input file: mwe.tex
[WARNING] build file: HTML parsing failed
[WARNING] build file: /usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaxml/luaxml-mod-xml.lua:175: Unbalanced Tag (/div) [char=1303]

line 27 column 1 - Error: unexpected </div> in <p>
line 36 column 1 - Error: unexpected </body> in <p>
line 36 column 8 - Error: unexpected </html> in <p>
This document has errors that must be fixed before
using HTML Tidy to generate a tidied up version.

[WARNING] domfilter: DOM parsing of mwe.html failed:
[WARNING] domfilter: /usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaxml/luaxml-mod-xml.lua:175: Unbalanced Tag (/div) [char=1303]

[WARNING] build file: HTML parsing failed
[WARNING] build file: /usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaxml/luaxml-mod-xml.lua:175: Unbalanced Tag (/body) [char=1525]

line 32 column 1 - Error: unexpected </body> in <p>
line 32 column 8 - Error: unexpected </html> in <p>
This document has errors that must be fixed before
using HTML Tidy to generate a tidied up version.

[WARNING] domfilter: DOM parsing of mwepa1.html failed:
[WARNING] domfilter: /usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaxml/luaxml-mod-xml.lua:175: Unbalanced Tag (/body) [char=1525]

HTML Tidy for Linux version 5.7.16
[STATUS]  tex4ebook: Conversion finished
```

mwe.log

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=latex 2021.2.14)  3 MAR 2021 22:17
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**\makeatletter\def\HCode{\futurelet\HCode\HChar}\def\HChar{\ifx"\HCode\def\HCo
de"##1"{\Link##1}\expandafter\HCode\else\expandafter\Link\fi}\def\Link#1.a.b.c.
{\g@addto@macro\@documentclasshook{\RequirePackage[#1,html]{tex4ht}\RequirePack
age{tex4ebook}}\let\HCode\documentstyle\def\documentstyle{\let\documentstyle\HC
ode\expandafter\def\csname tex4ht\endcsname{#1,html}\def\HCode####1{\documentst
yle[tex4ht,}\@ifnextchar[{\HCode}{\documentstyle[tex4ht]}}}\makeatother\HCode x
html,,charset=utf-8,charset=utf-8,epub,uni-html4.a.b.c.\input "\detokenize{mwe.
tex}"
(./mwe.tex (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk10.clo
File: bk10.clo 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count177
\c@chapter=\count178
\c@section=\count179
\c@subsection=\count180
\c@subsubsection=\count181
\c@paragraph=\count182
\c@subparagraph=\count183
\c@figure=\count184
\c@table=\count185
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/tex4ht.sty
version 2020-10-16-13:47
Package: tex4ht 
\tmp:toks=\toks15
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/usepackage.4ht
version 2020-10-17-13:53
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tex4ebook/tex4ebook.sty
Package: tex4ebook 2016/03/31 version 0.1d
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count186
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2020-10-07 v3.14 Key value format for package options (HO)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
)) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2020/09/09 v1.2b Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/graphics-hooks.4ht
version 2020-10-17-13:53
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2020/08/30 v1.4c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: dvips.def on input line 105.
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/dvips.def
File: dvips.def 2017/06/20 v3.1d Graphics/color driver for dvips
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen139
\Gin@req@width=\dimen140
)) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/tabularx.sty
Package: tabularx 2020/01/15 v2.11c `tabularx' package (DPC)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty
Package: array 2020/10/01 v2.5c Tabular extension package (FMi)
\col@sep=\dimen141
\ar@mcellbox=\box47
\extrarowheight=\dimen142
\NC@list=\toks17
\extratabsurround=\skip49
\backup@length=\skip50
\ar@cellbox=\box48
)
\TX@col@width=\dimen143
\TX@old@table=\dimen144
\TX@old@col=\dimen145
\TX@target=\dimen146
\TX@delta=\dimen147
\TX@cols=\count187
\TX@ftn=\toks18
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/tex4ht.4ht
version 2020-03-12-14:03
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
 TeX4ht info is available in the log file 
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/tex4ht.sty
version 2020-10-16-13:47
--- needs --- tex4ht mwe ---
\tmp:cnt=\count188
(./mwe.tmp)
\tmp:dim=\skip51
l.1460 --- TeX4ht warning --- No file mwe.xref ---
\:refout=\write3
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht
version 2020-11-27-15:09
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht
version 2020-11-09-14:28
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht
version 2020-09-18-15:30
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-uni.4ht)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht
version 2020-11-27-15:09
TeX4ht package options: xhtml,charset=utf-8,epub,uni-html4,html
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht
version 2020-11-09-14:28
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht
version 2020-09-18-15:30
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-uni.4ht)
\:tokwrite=\toks19
\:tokpage=\toks20
\:tocout=\write4
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht
version 2020-11-27-15:09
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht
version 2020-11-09-14:28
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht
version 2020-09-18-15:30
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-uni.4ht) (/usr/share/texmf-di
st/tex/generic/tex4ht/latex.4ht
version 2020-10-03-14:24
LaTeX Info: Redefining \_ on input line 173.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \, on input line 787.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \; on input line 788.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \! on input line 789.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \: on input line 790.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \> on input line 791.
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht
version 2020-11-27-15:09
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht
version 2020-11-09-14:28
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht
version 2020-09-18-15:30
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-uni.4ht) (/usr/share/texmf-di
st/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht
version 2020-11-27-15:09
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht
version 2020-11-09-14:28
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht
version 2020-09-18-15:30
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-uni.4ht)) (/usr/share/texmf-d
ist/tex/generic/tex4ht/fontmath.4ht
version 2018-11-06-15:55
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht
version 2020-11-27-15:09
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht
version 2020-11-09-14:28
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht
version 2020-09-18-15:30
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-uni.4ht)) (/usr/share/texmf-d
ist/tex/generic/tex4ht/book.4ht (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4
.4ht
version 2020-11-27-15:09
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht
version 2020-11-09-14:28
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht
version 2020-09-18-15:30
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-uni.4ht)) (/usr/share/texmf-d
ist/tex/latex/tex4ebook/tex4ebook.4ht
\opf:htmlid=\count189
\navpoint=\count190
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/graphicx.4ht
version 2018-10-01-14:24
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht
version 2020-11-27-15:09
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht
version 2020-11-09-14:28
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht
version 2020-09-18-15:30
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-uni.4ht)) (/usr/share/texmf-d
ist/tex/generic/tex4ht/graphics.4ht (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/h
tml4.4ht
version 2020-11-27-15:09
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht
version 2020-11-09-14:28
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht
version 2020-09-18-15:30
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-uni.4ht)) (/usr/share/texmf-d
ist/tex/generic/tex4ht/dvips.4ht
version 2009-05-21-09:32
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht
version 2020-11-27-15:09
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht
version 2020-11-09-14:28
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht
version 2020-09-18-15:30
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-uni.4ht)) (/usr/share/texmf-d
ist/tex/generic/tex4ht/tabularx.4ht
version 2009-05-21-09:32
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht
version 2020-11-27-15:09
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht
version 2020-11-09-14:28
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht
version 2020-09-18-15:30
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-uni.4ht)) (/usr/share/texmf-d
ist/tex/generic/tex4ht/array.4ht
version 2009-05-21-09:32
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht
version 2020-11-27-15:09
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht
version 2020-11-09-14:28
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht
version 2020-09-18-15:30
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-uni.4ht)) (/usr/share/texmf-d
ist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4.4ht
version 2020-11-27-15:09
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht
version 2020-11-09-14:28
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht
version 2020-09-18-15:30
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-uni.4ht)) (/usr/share/texmf-d
ist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def
File: l3backend-dvips.def 2020-09-24 L3 backend support: dvips
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box49
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count191
\l__pdf_backend_content_box=\box50
\l__pdf_backend_model_box=\box51
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count192
\g__pdf_backend_link_int=\count193
\g__pdf_backend_link_sf_int=\count194
)
No file mwe.aux.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
--- file mwe.css ---
[1

] [2

] [3] [4]
--- file mwepa1.html ---
No file mwe.4tc
[5] [6

] (./mwe.aux) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `tabularx` environment doesn't close previous paragraph in some cases. It is quite easy to fix this using the following configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\ConfigureEnv{tabularx}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP}{}{}{}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

It configures the `tabularx` environment to close the previous paragraph before it outputs the `<table>` tag.

Here is the original output:

```
<!--l. 7--><p class="noindent" >
 <table id="TBL-3" class="tabular"
```

and this is the fixed output:

```
   <p class='noindent'></p>
      <table id='TBL-3' class='tabular'>
```

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks!